# AWK - compare two 1-column files for matching strings then write a file with updated info

Tags: string, awk, compare, match

I have a problem on comparing two files of different no. of lines and use info from a file to update the other. I have tried various key examples that I found online but none seems to work.

Hopefully you could help me with this one.

I have two files:

```
$ cat 1.txt
>01234
NNNNNNNNAAAAAANNNNNNAAAAANNNNAAAAANNNNAA
>17321
SSSSSSKKKKKKLLLLLIIIIIIMMMMMMNNNNNNAAAA
>13920
ZZZZZZZYYYYYYYAAAAAAABBBBBBBCCCCNNNNNNNNNN
...
...
(>1000 lines)


$ cat 2.txt
hbcd/efgh/z-01234/2000
hbcd/efgh/zw-11000/2000
hbcd/efgh/t-13290/2000
...
...
(<1000 lines)
```

My intention is to have an updated file `1.txt`, with updated lines but also to keep the lines that are not matched in file `2.txt`, so could be saved as a new file as follows:

```
$ cat 3.txt
>abcd/efgh/z-01234/2000
NNNNNNNNAAAAAANNNNNNAAAAANNNNAAAAANNNNAA
>17321
SSSSSSKKKKKKLLLLLIIIIIIMMMMMMNNNNNNAAAA
>abcd/efgh/t-13290/2000
ZZZZZZZYYYYYYYAAAAAAABBBBBBBCCCCNNNNNNNNNN
...
...
```

I have tried something like this:
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0;next}{a[$1]=$0}END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt

or like this (to search based on the substring in 1.txt):
awk 'NR==FNR{a[substr($0,2,5)]=$0;next}{a[$1]=$0}END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt

but the I get mixed up lines in the output file, something like this (or even without the lines from 2.txt, respectively):

> 01234
> 17321
> SSSSSSKKKKKKLLLLLIIIIIIMMMMMMNNNNNNAAAA
> abcd/efgh/t-13290/2000
> NNNNNNNNAAAAAANNNNNNAAAAANNNNAAAAANNNNAA
> ZZZZZZZYYYYYYYAAAAAAABBBBBBBCCCCNNNNNNNNNN

I haven't used awk for very long time and I'm not sure how the arrays and keys work.

Update:
I have tried to write an awk script, to do the above. The condition to check them works but somehow I still have a problem with writing the lines from 1.txt that don't match the ones from 2.txt.

```
BEGIN{
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    maxi = 0;
    maxj = 0;
    maxk = 0;
    FS = "\/";
}

FILENAME == ARGV[1]{
    header1=substr($0,1,1);
    if(header1==">"){
        ++maxi;
        seqcode1[maxi]=substr($0,2,5);
#       printf("%s\n",seqcode1[maxi]);
    }
    else if(header1!=">"){
        ++maxk;
        seqFASTA[maxk]=$0;
#       print seqFASTA[maxk];
    }
}

FILENAME == ARGV[2]{
    header2=substr($0,1,1);
    if(header2=="h"){
        ++maxj;
        wholename[maxj]=$0;
        seqcode2[maxj]=substr($3,4,5);
#       printf("%s\n",seqcode2[maxj]);
    }
}

END{
    for(i=1;i<=maxi=maxk;i++){
      for(j=1;j<=maxj;j++){
        if(seqcode1[i] == seqcode2[j]) {
            printf("%s %s %s\n",seqcode1[i],seqcode2[j],wholename[j]);
        }
        else
          print seqcode1[i];
          print seqFASTA[k];
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem may be with declaring seqFASTA but I'm not sure where.

Thank you very much!
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `13920` should be `13290` in `1.txt`.

```sh
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($0, a, "/"); sub(/^[^-]+-/, "", a[3]); map[a[3]]=$0; next}
       (k=substr($0, 2)) in map{$0 = ">" map[k]} 1' 2.txt 1.txt
>hbcd/efgh/z-01234/2000
NNNNNNNNAAAAAANNNNNNAAAAANNNNAAAAANNNNAA
>17321
SSSSSSKKKKKKLLLLLIIIIIIMMMMMMNNNNNNAAAA
>hbcd/efgh/t-13290/2000
ZZZZZZZYYYYYYYAAAAAAABBBBBBBCCCCNNNNNNNNNN
```

Here are some alternate solutions:

```sh
# with GNU awk
awk 'NR==FNR{match($0, /-([0-9]+)/, a); map[a[1]]=$0; next}
     (k=substr($0, 2)) in map{$0 = ">" map[k]} 1' 2.txt 1.txt

# assuming '/' and '-' will always be similar to given sample
awk -F'[/-]' 'NR==FNR{map[$4]=">"$0; next}
              $2 in map{$0 = map[$2]} 1' 2.txt FS='>' 1.txt
```

Comment: Dear Sundeep,

Many thanks for your help. Yes, you're right about the 13920 typo.
I find your first solution the best for my data set. It works perfectly.
My best regards to you!